# How can I add Messages to SelfControl's whitelist?

Tags: macos

I am using OS X 10.9.2, and how can I add **Messages** to [SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com)'s whitelist?

Comment: You'll need to find the address of the iMessage servers (maybe with `netstat` ?) and then block them just like any other website.

Comment: @André How can I find iMessage servers? I am sorry, I am not familiar with Objective-C.

Comment: Search about the `netstat` command (it displays the local/remote IPs of all connections currently established), if you really can't figure it out then edit your question. And you don't have to know Objective-C, this has nothing to do with it.